# перевести строку в число python

Tags: python

имею массив ['28','12','11,2'] строк. Нужно сделать из него массив чисел. Я читал его из csv, поэтому код такой:

```
with open("..\csv\m.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    arrayDistance = []

    for row in reader:
         arrayDistance.append(float(row['distance']))

print(arrayDistance)
```

Выскакивает 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в строке `'11,2 '` вместо `запятой` должна быть `точка`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
In [1]: n = ['28','12','11,2'] 

In [2]: [float(i.replace(',', '.')) for i in n]                                                        
Out[2]: [28.0, 12.0, 11.2]
```

Используем генератор списков.
Но так как если во флоат передать строку с запятой мы получим ошибку `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`, то с помощью `replace` мы в числах заменили запятую на точку.

```py
with open("..\csv\m.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    arrayDistance = []

    for row in reader:
         arrayDistance.append(float(row['distance'].replace(',', '.')))

print(arrayDistance)
```

попробуйте вот так.

Answer (score 2):

> нужно в файле заменить ',' на '.'  – "11,2"

Или преобразовать в скрипте примерно так

```
with open("..\csv\m.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    arrayDistance = []

    for row in reader:
        new_str = row['distance'].replace(",", ".")
        arrayDistance.append(float(new_str))
print(arrayDistance)
```